# Insert selected item from listbox to multiline textbox cursor point

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, listbox

I have two fields,  text area and Listbox. When i select each item in listbox it has to display in text area with appending on the text in it.
and if i move the cursor before some text and select another item from listbox it must append the item where the cursor is placed.
i am fresher to this field so please help how do i do it??

i tried with this 
txtTemplatebody.Text = txtTemplatebody.Text + lbTokenList.SelectedItem.ToString(); 
but when i tried to append on front it's not working.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You should improve your question. It's very unclear.

Comment: can you post more code?

Comment: where ever i keep my cursor in text area, selected item from listbox must append it their.